# Multiline editing vs 2015 for variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

How to edit all those highlited variables or keywords at once

[image]

Private Sub _checkExistance()
    Dim test As String = ""

```
test = "appears here"

Try
    test = "appears"
Catch ex As Exception
    test = "appear"
End Try
```

End Sub

Is there any specific shortcut instead of using CTRL + H and replacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rename the variable, you can use:
right click on the variable -> Rename = All referenzes where change
or use the  shortcut F2

Edit 1:

The shortcut F2 is only active, if the options is set on Visual C# 2005. I think your options are Visual Basic 6, in this case you haven't a shortcut. You have two possibility to solve this.

1. Change the mapping scheme
   Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard 
   Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme: chose Visual C# 2005 (then it is F2) or Visual Studio 6(then it is Ctrl+R)
2. Use new shortcut in:
   Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard 
   Use new shortcut in…

Comment: That is something im looking for but is there any shortcut instead going right click....

Comment: Yes the shortcut is F2

Comment: It opens me a Object Browser on F2 shortcut